# How to align numbers on decimal point in latex

Tags: horizontal-alignment, siunitx

I would love to align the columns (containing the numbers) on the decimal point. I have been reading about the package 'siuntix', but this fails to correctly incorporate the numbers in the parentheses below, and the asterisk is also hard to deal with.

Does anyone knows how to align the numbers in the table below?

Thank you very much!

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{l c c c c}
\hline
    & $\beta_1$ & $\beta_2$ & $\beta_2$ & $\beta_4$ \\ \hline
XXX & 1.23      & 0.23$^*$    & -1.23      & 2.41$^*$      \\
XXX & (-1.39)    & (4.23)   & (4.21)    & (-2.92)    \\
XXX & 2.51      & 2.66      & 0.25      & 1.52      \\
XXX & (2.11)    & (4.11)    & (-2.45)    & (5.21)    \\
XXX & 1.67$^*$      & -3.15      & 0.82      & 1.11$^*$      \\
XXX & (1.23)    & (-3.11)    & (2.11)    & (4.11)    \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: For the siunitx version, maybe have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49869/36296

Answer (score 17):

If all you need to achieve is to align the numbers on their decimal markers, using the `siunitx` package may be a bit of overkill. The `dcolumn` package will let you achieve your objective as well.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{dcolumn,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{l *{4}{d{3.3}} }
\toprule
& \mc{$\beta_1$} & \mc{$\beta_2$} & \mc{$\beta_2$} & \mc{$\beta_4$} \\ 
\midrule
XXX &   1.23    &   0.23^*  &  -1.23    &   2.41^* \\
XXX & (-1.39)   &  (4.23)   &  (4.21)   & (-2.92)  \\ \addlinespace
XXX &   2.51    &   2.66    &   0.25    &   1.52   \\
XXX &  (2.11)   &  (4.11)   & (-2.45)   &  (5.21)  \\ \addlinespace
XXX &  1.67^*   &  -3.15    &   0.82    &   1.11^* \\
XXX & (1.23)    & (-3.11)   &  (2.11)   &  (4.11)  \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast reply! Is it maybe possible to shrink the space in between the columns and still remain the beta (header of the column) in the middle of the column? Later on I am having larger tables and they are not fitting the page. Also, just applying \small is not enough.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Stefan - The amount of inter-column whitespace is governed by the length parameter `\tabcolsep`; its default value is `6pt` in most document classes. You could try issuing the instruction `\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}` immediately before `\begin{tabular}{....}` and see if that helps.

Comment: +1. Nice answer. It seems tex.stackexchange doesn't render LaTeX as, for example, math.stackexchange do. That's awful !!!.

Comment: @FelixMarin - I hate to have to contradict you outright, but I believe it's required here. The main purpose of TeX.SE is to develop and offer solutions to typesetting issues by analyzing and improving TeX and LaTeX code. MathJax is disabled intentionally on TeX.SE: people actually want to see the code, *not* the output generated by MathJax. Hence, the setup is not awful at all...

Comment: @Mico,  I just tried to write a similar table with `siunitx`, but I failed. reports error: "misplaced-sign-token" (caused with `(-3.11)`). so it looks like the tables in your answer can not be written with `siunitx`.  +1 for nice answer!

Comment: @Zarko - Thanks! Indeed, I find that if alignment on the decimal marker is what's required, the facilities of the `dcolumn` package are much less fussy than what's provided by the `S` column type of the `siunitx` package. Of course, the `siunitx` package does many many other things, besides providing a method for decimal alignment of numbers.

Comment: @Mico why are you using multicolumn for a normal single-column entry at the top of the table? I'm confused, I have seen other people do it as well.

Comment: @BlackJack21 - The "multi" component of the macro named `\multicolumn` is an unfortunate misnomer: `\multicolumn` can operate on single columns (and single cells) every bit as well as on multiple columns simultaneously. The purpose of the directive `\mc{$\beta_1$}`, which expands to `\multicolumn{1}{c}{$\beta_1$}`, is to change the *column type* -- just for the cell at hand -- from `d{3.3}` to `c`. This is needed since `$\beta_1$` is not a number with up to three ordinary digits and three decimal digits. It's better to apply the `c` (centering) column type for this cell, isn't it?