# Help Recreating a Table

Tags: tables, siunitx

I am trying to recreate this table using LaTeX.

[image]

I want to additionally align the decimals. I have tried using [this code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/374638) to do so.

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Table}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{l *{4}{d{3.3}} }
\toprule
Variable & Weighted Test Statistic  & Unweighted p-value & Weighted Test Statistic  & Unweighted p-value\\
\midrule
Attendance Rate&0.55&0.0875&2.15&$<$0.0001\\
Test Average&4.14&0.0320&4.68&0.0080\\
Final Exam&4.12&0.0022&1.99&0.1590\\
\makecell{Data Analysis \\ Assignment Average}&20.98&$<$0.0001&17.42&$<$0.0001\\
Quiz Average&3.88&0.0035&2.33&0.0399\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Kruskal-Wallis Tests by Semester}
\end{table}

\end{frame}
```

This code created the following table. There are several things I would like to fix. Namely

- Adding fall and spring panels like in the original table
- Aligning the values associated with the "Data Analysis Assignment Average" at the top of that row
- Fixing the < signs
- Fixing the headings so that they can be within the bounds of a PowerPoint slide. I tried using the makecell{.} function but it didn't work the same as with the \midrule components.

[image]

**Note:** I wasn't sure what to title this question so feel free to change it.

**Edit:**

Using Zarko's code, I get the following.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `tabularx`, `siunitx` and `makecell` packages:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\footnotesize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{table}
\caption{Kruskal-Wallis Tests by Semester}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\small
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}
                            >{\raggedright\linespread{0.84}\selectfont}X
                            *{2}{S[table-format=2.2]
                                  S[table-format=1.4,
                                    table-comparator=true]}
                            @{}}
    \toprule
\multirow[b]{3}{=}{Variable}
    &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{Fall} &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Spring}  \\
    \cmidrule(r){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
    &   {\thead{Weighted\\ Test Statistic}}
        &   {\thead{Unweighted\\ p-value}}
            &   {\thead{Weighted\\ Test Statistic}}
                &   {\thead{Unweighted\\ p-value}}           \\
    \midrule
Attendance Rate                     &  0.55 &  0.0875 &  2.15 & <0.0001\\
Test Average                        &  4.14 &  0.0320 &  4.68 &  0.0080\\
Final Exam                          &  4.12 &  0.0022 &  1.99 &  0.1590\\
Data Analysis Assignment Average    & 20.98 & <0.0001 & 17.42 & <0.0001\\
Quiz Average                        &  3.88 &  0.0035 &  2.33 &  0.0399\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I used your code and "Variable" looks weird. I added a picture to my original post. Any idea what happened there?

Comment: @Remy, if you not obtain the same result as I show, than  you or change something in my code or you have installed older version of used packages. I test my code with recent versions of all used packages.

Comment: I'm using Overleaf. When I just use multirow{Variable}, I get what you have except variable is adjacent to "Fall" and "Spring." Does it matter what other packages I'm using to go along with those?

Comment: @Remy, oh Overleaf` .... it hasn't installed decent ˙\multirow` package. You need to change line `\multirow[b]{3}{=}{Variable}` to older syntax `\multirow{5}{*}{Variable}`.

Comment: Thanks so much. I think your code is what I'll go with.

Comment: @Remy, if you will do so, than it will be nice to accept mine answer :-)

Comment: Done! Wasn't sure if it's okay to switch the accepted answer or not.

Answer (score 3):

Here my suggestions.

I have not met the point two. It seems more elegant to me aligned at the bottom, or as showed here, aligned at the middle. But if you disagree, just change the `m` column by a `p`. Anyway, with `p`,`m` or `b` the main point is that without awful the horizontal rows, this table needs some extra vertical space between rows to mark clearly where start/end the text of the multiline cell. Otherwise, the "Variable" column is a mess.

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}{D{.}{\cdot}{-1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{table}
\caption{Kruskal-Wallis Tests by Semester}
\footnotesize\tabcolsep0em
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\raggedright}m{10em}dddd}\toprule & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Fall} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Spring} \\
\cmidrule(r){2-3}
\cmidrule(l){4-5}
\multicolumn{1}{X}{\leavevmode\newline Variable} & 
\multicolumn{1}{X}{\centering Weighted Test Statistic}  & 
\multicolumn{1}{X}{\centering Unweighted p-value} & 
\multicolumn{1}{X}{\centering Weighted Test Statistic}  & 
\multicolumn{1}{X}{\centering Unweighted p-value} \tabularnewline
\cmidrule(r){1-1}
\cmidrule(rl){2-2}
\cmidrule(rl){3-3}
\cmidrule(rl){4-4}
\cmidrule(rl){5-5}
Attendance Rate                     &  0.55 &  0.0875 &  2.15 & <0.0001\\
Test Average                        &  4.14 &  0.0320 &  4.68 &  0.0080\\
Final Exam                          &  4.12 &  0.0022 &  1.99 &  0.1590\\
Data Analysis Assignment Average    & 20.98 & <0.0001 & 17.42 & <0.0001\\
Quiz Average                        &  3.88 &  0.0035 &  2.33 &  0.0399\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How can I make the decimals not be in the center but down? It looks like a multiplication sign.

Comment: @Reny In old British typography, the interpunct is the formal decimal point. As using full stops is easier in computers, this style is disappearing, however is still used in some good academic journals.  Change this is as simple as replace on line 3 the `\cdot` by   `.` or  `,`  or whatever that you want as decimal separator.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for your purposes. I used the article class for this but I think you can change it to beamer and use the `\frametitle{}` option in lieu of the caption and you can adjust the font size as needed using `\footnotesize` or anything else that can fit the dimensions of the slide. In addition, you can add the `\begin{frame}` and `\end{frame}` to the beginning and end of the table chunk of code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \caption{Kruskal-Wallis Tests by Semester}
    \begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{LCCCC}
        \\
        \hline
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Falll}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Spring} \\
        \hline
        Variable & Weighted Test Statistic  & Unweighted p-value & Weighted Test Statistic  & Unweighted p-value\\
        \hline
        Attendance Rate&0.55&0.0875&2.15&$<$0.0001\\
        Test Average&4.14&0.0320&4.68&0.0080\\
        Final Exam&4.12&0.0022&1.99&0.1590\\
        Data Analysis&&&&\\ 
        Assignment Average&20.98&$<$0.0001&17.42&$<$0.0001\\
       Quiz Average&3.88&0.0035&2.33&0.0399\\
       \hline 
    \end{tabulary}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**Edit:**

For beamer class,

```
\begin{frame}
\footnotesize %Or whatever other size you need
\frametitle{MY TABLE} %Frame Title
\begin{table}
    \caption{Kruskal-Wallis Tests by Semester}
    \begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{LCCCC}
        \\
        \hline
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Falll}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Spring} \\
        \hline
        Variable & Weighted Test Statistic  & Unweighted p-value & Weighted Test Statistic  & Unweighted p-value\\
        \hline
        Attendance Rate&0.55&0.0875&2.15&$<$0.0001\\
        Test Average&4.14&0.0320&4.68&0.0080\\
        Final Exam&4.12&0.0022&1.99&0.1590\\
        Data Analysis&&&&\\ 
        Assignment Average&20.98&$<$0.0001&17.42&$<$0.0001\\
       Quiz Average&3.88&0.0035&2.33&0.0399\\
       \hline 
    \end{tabulary}
\end{table}
\end{frame}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried adding your packages but it made every slide look weird. I have edited my post with a picture. Would it help if I showed each package I'm currently using?

Comment: I think your problem might come from the `fullpage` package because I never use that for beamer. If that is not it, please let me know what packages you are using.

Comment: That worked! Could you please edit your post to show where the font size adjustment goes?

Comment: I added it and hope it works for your purposes!