# Problem with Decimal Aligning on Outreg2 regression table

Tags: tables, siunitx

Guys anyone can figure out whatt's wrong here? I got this table from outreg2 stata and did some edit based on clemen's answer from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49869/178207). Thanks!

```
\documentclass[]{article}


\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx}
\usepackage[margin=1 in]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs, longtable}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{8.5in} \setlength{\pdfpageheight}{11in}
\begin{document}
\sisetup{
  input-symbols         = (),
  table-format          = -1.4,
  table-space-text-post = ***,
  table-align-text-post = false,
  group-digits          = false
}
\begin{tabular}{l *{8}{S}} \hline
 & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6) & (7) & (8) \\
Variables & FullD & FullD & FullD & FullD & FullD & FullD & FullD & FullD \\ \hline
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
STI\_30 & 0.301*** & 0.179** & 0.152* & 0.159 & -0.000 & 0.107 & 0.097 & 0.115 \\
 & (0.087) & (0.085) & (0.085) & (0.097) & (0.003) & (0.084) & (0.094) & (0.105) \\
Produce\_Full\_SR &  & 0.349*** & 0.321*** & 0.303* & 0.318*** & 0.270*** & 0.244*** & 0.257*** \\
 &  & (0.071) & (0.074) & (0.170) & (0.074) & (0.074) & (0.078) & (0.090) \\
Has\_Sus\_Efforts &  &  & 0.078*** & 0.077*** & 0.245*** & 0.001 & 0.046** & 0.129*** \\
 &  &  & (0.020) & (0.020) & (0.094) & (0.013) & (0.019) & (0.041) \\
1o.STI\_30\#1o.Produce\_Full\_SR &  &  &  & 0.000 &  &  &  &  \\
 &  &  &  & (0.000) &  &  &  &  \\
1o.STI\_30\#1o.Has\_Sus\_Efforts &  &  &  &  & 0.000 &  &  &  \\
 &  &  &  &  & (0.000) &  &  &  \\
Water\_Efforts &  &  &  &  &  & 0.168*** &  &  \\
 &  &  &  &  &  & (0.039) &  &  \\
C\_or\_S &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0.202*** &  \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  & (0.066) &  \\
C\_or\_S1 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0.221** \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & (0.100) \\
Constant & 0.054*** & 0.029*** & -0.001 & -0.002 & 0.000 & -0.001 & 0.000 & 0.000 \\
 & (0.010) & (0.008) & (0.003) & (0.003) & (0.003) & (0.003) & (0.000) & (0.000) \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
Observations & 566 & 555 & 552 & 552 & 552 & 552 & 252 & 140 \\
Year FE & No & No & No & No & No & No & No & No \\
Nb of obs & 566 & 555 & 552 & 552 & 552 & 552 & 252 & 140 \\
 Adjusted R-squared & 0.0696 & 0.211 & 0.233 & 0.232 & 0.234 & 0.275 & 0.199 & 0.133 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{9}{c}{ Robust standard errors in parentheses} \\
\multicolumn{9}{c}{ *** p$<$0.01, ** p$<$0.05, * p$<$0.1} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Johnny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cells in `S`-type columns which do not conform to the expected numeric format -- including cells such as `(1)`, `FullD`, `No`, `552`, and `0.0696` -- must be centered.

This is done most easily by encasing the cell contents in curly braces. E.g., instead of

```
Variables & FullD & FullD & FullD & FullD & FullD & FullD & FullD & FullD
```

you need to input

```
Variables & {FullD} & {FullD} & {FullD} & {FullD} & {FullD} & {FullD} & {FullD} & {FullD}
```

As the table is quite wide, it needs to be rendered in landscape format. One way to do this is to load the `rotating` package and employ its `sidewaystable` environment.

Finally, since you're loading the `booktabs` package, do make use of its `\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\bottomrule`, and `\addlinespace` directives instead of `\hline`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{8.5in} 
\setlength{\pdfpageheight}{11in}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,array}
\usepackage{siunitx} % don't use 'detect-all' switch unless you know what you're doing
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating} % for 'sidewaystable' env.

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\sisetup{
  input-symbols         = (),
  table-format          = -1.3,
  table-space-text-post = ***,
  table-align-text-post = false,
  group-digits          = false
}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}l *{8}{S} @{}} 
\toprule
          & {(1)} & {(2)} & {(3)} & {(4)} & {(5)} & {(6)} & {(7)} & {(8)} \\
Variables & {FullD} & {FullD} & {FullD} & {FullD} & {FullD} & {FullD} & {FullD} & {FullD} \\ 
\midrule
STI\_30   & 0.301*** & 0.179** & 0.152* & 0.159 & -0.000 & 0.107 & 0.097 & 0.115 \\
          & (0.087) & (0.085) & (0.085) & (0.097) & (0.003) & (0.084) & (0.094) & (0.105) \\
Produce\_Full\_SR &  & 0.349*** & 0.321*** & 0.303* & 0.318*** & 0.270*** & 0.244*** & 0.257*** \\
          &  & (0.071) & (0.074) & (0.170) & (0.074) & (0.074) & (0.078) & (0.090) \\
Has\_Sus\_Efforts &  &  & 0.078*** & 0.077*** & 0.245*** & 0.001 & 0.046** & 0.129*** \\
          &  &  & (0.020) & (0.020) & (0.094) & (0.013) & (0.019) & (0.041) \\
1o.STI\_30\#1o.Produce\_Full\_SR &  &  &  & 0.000 &  &  &  &  \\
          &  &  &  & (0.000) &  &  &  &  \\
1o.STI\_30\#1o.Has\_Sus\_Efforts &  &  &  &  & 0.000 &  &  &  \\
          &  &  &  &  & (0.000) &  &  &  \\
Water\_Efforts &  &  &  &  &  & 0.168*** &  &  \\
          &  &  &  &  &  & (0.039) &  &  \\
C\_or\_S  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0.202*** &  \\
          &  &  &  &  &  &  & (0.066) &  \\
C\_or\_S1 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0.221** \\
          &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & (0.100) \\
Constant  & 0.054*** & 0.029*** & -0.001 & -0.002 & 0.000 & -0.001 & 0.000 & 0.000 \\
          & (0.010) & (0.008) & (0.003) & (0.003) & (0.003) & (0.003) & (0.000) & (0.000) \\
\midrule
Observations & {566} & {555} & {552} & {552} & {552} & {552} & {252} & {140} \\
Year FE      & {No} & {No} & {No} & {No} & {No} & {No} & {No} & {No} \\
Nr.\ of obs  & {566} & {555} & {552} & {552} & {552} & {552} & {252} & {140} \\
Adj.\ R\textsuperscript{2} & {0.0696} & {0.211} & {0.233} & {0.232} & {0.234} & {0.275} & {0.199} & {0.133} \\ 
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{9}{c}{Robust standard errors in parentheses} \\
\multicolumn{9}{c}{$^{***}\ p<0.01$; $^{**}\ p<0.05$, $^{*}\ p<0.1$} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice thanks Mico! can i know what is the use of @{} in \begin{tabular}{@{}l *{8}{S} @{}}

Comment: And I have another qn: how do you get it p to be italicized  at the last row??

Comment: @Johnny - Your code has `*** p$<$0.01`; I changed it to `$^{***}\ p<0.01$`. Put differently, I made `p` part of the "formula" `p<0.01`. This affects not only the shape of the letter "p" but also the spacing around the `<` symbol. The `@{}` particles in `{@{} l *{8}{S} @{}}` serve to suppress the whitespace padding that would otherwise be inserted to the left of the first column and to the right of the final column. This padding is not needed if one doesn't require vertical bars at the left-hand and right-hand edges of the `tabular` environment.

Comment: Thanks Mico for the explanation! What are the (backslash and space) before the p's for btw?

Comment: btw do I need to add the braces (for my first qn in the post) manually? is there any keyboard shortcuts/ codes that can automate the adding of braces for non-numeric elements?

Comment: @Johnny - The `\ ` ("backslash"-"space") command sequence inserts a space. Since I don't know which editor you employ, I'm not in a position to provide advice on which keyboard shortcuts may be available to you. For what it's worth, here's how I performed the adding of curly braces around the `FullD` particles: I highlighted the row in question and instructed the editor to replace all instances of ` & ` ("space ampersand space") with `} & {`. Finally, i had to hand-tune the contents of the first and last cell in the row.